# Value error on loading a spectra using pyxspec

Tags: python-3.x, xspec

Trying to load a spectrum in a python notebook after importing the xspec module gives me the following error.

*PyCapsule_New called with null pointer*

What can be the possible mistake?

Comment: You should add more details, please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates one of files was not found, you may check the error message in the jupyter terminal.

Try to copy spectrum (.pha), background (.bak) and response (.rsp) files to the root path of your workspace then load xspec.Spectrum(filename).